# Was asymptotic expansion also a form of symmetry?

Tags: operators, symmetry, mathematics, asymptotics

Consider the infinitesimal expansion, which was used to describe the behavior of of the expression when taking the parameter to be small.

The infinitesimal expansion was usually used to describe the symmetry. The most famous was perhaps the lie algebra, where in the physics it started with some types of the generators, i.e.,

$$"\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} O\approx I+\epsilon A"$$
or
$$O=e^{i\epsilon T}=I+i\epsilon T, \epsilon <<1$$

(Both equations were not strictly mathematically justified in most of the physics textbooks, but should be familiar in what it meant. The "$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}$" meant taking $\epsilon$ to be some small number, so small such that $\epsilon f(x)>>\epsilon^2 f(y)$ for some smooth function $f(x)$, or that $\epsilon$ were "infinitesimally small".)

However, consider the asymptotic expansion, which was used to describe the behavior of the expression when taking the parameter to be large instead of to be small.

$$"\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \infty} O\approx A_1=I+(A_1 -I)"$$
or
$$O=e^{i\epsilon T}\approx A,\epsilon >>1$$

Could this asymptotic expansion also be describe some types of the symmetry? i.e.
$$"\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \infty} O\approx \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \infty}I+(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon})(A_1 -I) \approx \lim_{\epsilon_2\rightarrow 0} I+(1-\epsilon) A_2"$$

**A possible example**

One of the example might be the crossing symmetry in the scattering amplitude. Consider the time translation generator
$$e^{\frac{it H}{\hbar} }$$

taking $\psi_{in}$ to be $\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty} \psi(x,t)$ and $\psi_{out}$ to be $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \psi(x,t)$. Then the crossing symmetry in the scattering experiments might be considered as a type of such "asymptotic symmetry" in the $\epsilon >>1$ region, where in real experiment, "$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}$" meant taking $t$ to be some large but finite value, in the asympotic region.

Comment: You need to be much clearer about what you're doing here. $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} O$ doesn't actually *mean* anything since you haven't told us what $O$ is and how it depends on $\epsilon$. Why would one attempt a "limit" $\epsilon\to \infty$? Why is there still an $\epsilon$ on your r.h.s. in the first equation *after* taking the "limit" $\epsilon\to 0$? Are you trying to talk about the relationship between Lie groups of symmetries and their corresponding Lie algebras of infinitesimal symmetries here? If so, you need to be *much* more precise what $\epsilon\to\infty$ would mean in that context.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the $\epsilon$ on the right hand side  was just to indicate the logic, i.e. taking to be some small expansion, something quite small but not actually zero. Most textbook in QM or QFT didn't justify it in a strict mathematical definition any way. One example might be $\lim_\epsilon O$ to be explained as $O=e^{i\epsilon T}=I+i\epsilon T$ where $\epsilon T<<1$. I wasn't sure how to express it so that it could be understood without too much pretext.

Comment: @ACuriousMind $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow \infty}$ was very common to describe the behaviors of the system. In fact every scatter amplitude was in this region with $t_f\rightarrow \infty $, or equivalently, $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow \infty } e^{i \epsilon H}$. Speak of which this might be one of it, the crossing symmetry might be seen as a type of symmetry in the asymptotic region. Thank you.

Comment: Please *edit* your question if you think you can make it clearer instead of only leaving comments. However, you haven't really explained what you mean in your comments, either: Sure, sometimes limits like $t\to\infty$ occur in physics. What does any of that have to do with symmetries of the form $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\epsilon T}$, and what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @ACuriousMind (I was hoping someone could poke the question so that I could have a better understating of what I was asking. Asking the question sometimes equaled to solve it.) Considering the Hamiltonian of the time translation generator  $e^{\frac{i t H }{\hbar}}$, they were very much of the form consistent with $e^{i\epsilon T}$. The infinitesimal expansion taking $\epsilon$ to be something small was used to construct the symmetry group. However, what if one attempt to take the asymptotic expansion with $\epsilon>>1$? Could this also corresponding to some types of group?

Comment: @ACuriousMind It appeared that the crossing symmetry in the scattering amplitude might be seen as one of this example. If taking $t$ to be dimensionless such as the CFT, could the asymptotic expansion of $e^{i\epsilon T}$, i.e. $e^{\frac{itH}{\hbar}}$ with $\epsilon$ to be taken as a large number, be seen "crossing symmetry" group? And could this be generalized?(Not quite sure what was asking exactly.)